# Vite: Configuring multiple entries and specific output structure

Tags: reactjs, webpack, configuration, frontend, vite

I finally made the move to Vite from Webpack on a few small apps. But I am trying to figure out a way to have a vite config for a parent directory that has the rest of the apps. This is the structure of the source files -

```
├── package.json
├── vite.config.js
└── app1
    ├── vite.config.js
    ├── index.html
    └── src
        ├── main.jsx
        └── ...
└── app2
    ├── vite.config.js
    ├── index.html
    └── src
        ├── main.jsx
        └── ...

and so on
```

The only need for such a parent directory with a config is to build all of the nested apps at once and get the below output structure -

```
├── dist
    └── app1
        ├── build.js
        ├── index.html
        └── assets
           ├── css, fonts and images files
    └── app1
        ├── build.js
        ├── index.html
        └── assets
           ├── css, fonts and images files
```

I am not able to get the config for the parent file right. After several modifications, thanks to the multipage app documentation and some resources online, this is where I'm at right now, but the output part in rollupOptions is still a miss -

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';

const apps= ['app1', 'app2'];

const entries = {};
apps.forEach(app=> entries[app] = resolve(__dirname, `${app}/src/main.jsx`));

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    base: '',
    plugins: [react()],
    server: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 9015,
        open: true,
    },
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            input: { ...entries },
            output: {
                entryFileNames:'[name]/build.js',
                chunkFileNames: '[name].js',
                assetFileNames: '[name]/assets/[name].[ext]',
                manualChunks: undefined,
            },
        },
    },

    clean: true,
    outDir: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
});
```

I'd appreciate any help or pointers in getting the config right. Thanks in advance! And Vite is awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import path from "node:path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@app": path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    },
  },

  build: {
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1600,
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `react/[name].js`,
        chunkFileNames: `react/[name].js`,
        assetFileNames: `react/[name].[ext]`,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Your goal is to build each app and have their output in separate directories inside the dist folder. Your `vite.config.js` in the parent directory should handle this scenario.

Your current configuration seems close, but there's an issue with the output section in your `rollupOptions`. To achieve your desired output structure, you need to customize the `dir` option within the `output` object. Here's how you can modify your `vite.config.js` in the parent directory:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';

const apps = ['app1', 'app2'];

const entries = {};
apps.forEach(app => (entries[app] = resolve(__dirname, 
`${app}/src/main.jsx`)));

export default defineConfig({
  base: '',
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9015,
    open: true,
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: { ...entries },
      output: {
        // Use the dir option to output to separate directories for eachapp
        dir: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        entryFileNames: '[name]/build.js',
        chunkFileNames: '[name].js',
        assetFileNames: '[name]/assets/[name].[ext]',                
        manualChunks: undefined,
      },
    },
  },
  clean: true,
});
```

The main changes I made are:

- I added the `dir` property to the `output` object. This tells Vite where
  to output the built files.
- I changed the `entryFileNames` property to
  use the `[name]/build.js` format. This will create a separate build
  file for each app.
- I changed the `chunkFileNames` property to use the
  `[name].js` format. This will create a separate chunk file for each
  app.
- I changed the `assetFileNames` property to use the
  `[name]/assets/[name].[ext]` format. This will create a separate assets
  directory for each app.

This configuration will build each app and output its assets, chunks, and entry files in separate directories within the dist folder.

Comment: Does the dir property make a difference here? I included that (as the other filenames properties are already in place) and the output is still not the way I'd like it to be. It generates separate directories for font and css files (like index/assets/index.css) and the app builds do not have index.html. There is also an index.esm.js file in dist/ .