How to build vite each css files in a specific path (JS path working but not for CSS files) (Fixed!)
Updated!!!
I tried the below code and it put all my JS files into the correct folder structure but unfortunately it not working for CSS files. Can someone help me?

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";
import path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        outDir: "public/build/assets",
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                "js/app": path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/js/app.js"),
                "js/bootstrap": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/bootstrap.js"
                ),
                "js/vendor": path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/js/vendor.js"),
                "js/sockets/all": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/sockets/all.js"
                ),
                "js/layouts/smart": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/layouts/smart.js"
                ),
                "js/libraries/cs": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/libraries/cs.js"
                ),
                "js/libraries/skin": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/libraries/skin.js"
                ),
                "js/libraries/vertex": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/libraries/vertex.js"
                ),
                "js/libraries/widget": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/libraries/widget.js"
                ),
                "js/app/layouts/bxslider": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/app/layouts/bxslider.js"
                ),
                "js/app/layouts/page": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/app/layouts/page.js"
                ),
                "js/app/layouts/portal": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/app/layouts/portal.js"
                ),
                "js/app/modules/admin/managing/listing": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/app/modules/admin/managing/listing.js"
                ),
                "js/app/modules/admin/member/member": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/app/modules/admin/member/member.js"
                ),
                "js/config/core/dev/app": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/config/core/dev/app.js"
                ),
                "css/app": path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/css/app.css"),
                "css/vendor": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/css/vendor.css"
                ),
                "css/app/layouts/cms": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/css/app/layouts/cms.css"
                ),
                "css/app/layouts/auth": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/css/app/layouts/auth.css"
                ),
                "css/app/layouts/page": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/css/app/layouts/page.css"
                ),
                "css/app/layouts/admin": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/css/app/layouts/admin.css"
                ),
                "css/app/layouts/portal": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/css/app/layouts/portal.css"
                ),
            },
            output: {
                entryFileNames: (chunkInfo) => {
                    if (chunkInfo.name.startsWith("js/")) {
                        return `${chunkInfo.name}.js`; // Avoid adding 'js/' again
                    }
                    if (chunkInfo.name.startsWith("css/")) {
                        return `${chunkInfo.name}.css`; // Avoid adding 'css/' again
                    }
                    return `${chunkInfo.name}.js`; // Default
                },
                chunkFileNames: (chunkInfo) => {
                    if (chunkInfo.name.startsWith("js/")) {
                        return `${chunkInfo.name}.js`; // Same logic for chunks
                    }
                    if (chunkInfo.name.startsWith("css/")) {
                        return `${chunkInfo.name}.css`;
                    }
                    return `${chunkInfo.name}.js`; // Default
                },
                assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
                    if (assetInfo.name?.endsWith(".css")) {
                        // Place general CSS files in the correct folder
                        if (assetInfo.name.includes("layouts")) {
                            return `css/app/layouts/[name].[hash][extname]`;
                        }
                        return `css/[name].[hash][extname]`;
                    }

                    if (assetInfo.name?.endsWith(".js")) {
                        return `js/[name].[hash][extname]`;
                    }
                    return `assets/[name].[hash][extname]`;
                },
                sourcemap: true,
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                "resources/css/app.css",
                "resources/css/vendor.css",
                "resources/css/app/layouts/cms.css",
                "resources/css/app/layouts/auth.css",
                "resources/css/app/layouts/page.css",
                "resources/css/app/layouts/admin.css",
                "resources/css/app/layouts/portal.css",
                "resources/js/app.js",
                "resources/js/bootstrap.js",
                "resources/js/vendor.js",
                "resources/js/sockets/all.js",
                "resources/js/layouts/smart.js",
                "resources/js/libraries/cs.js",
                "resources/js/libraries/skin.js",
                "resources/js/libraries/vertex.js",
                "resources/js/libraries/widget.js",
                "resources/js/app/layouts/bxslider.js",
                "resources/js/app/layouts/page.js",
                "resources/js/app/layouts/portal.js",
                "resources/js/app/modules/admin/managing/listing.js",
                "resources/js/app/modules/admin/member/member.js",
                "resources/js/config/core/dev/app.js",
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});


Old question!!
I want to achieve a similar way to below using Vite,

Below is the code I tried but all the js and cs files are built inside the public/build/assets folder. But I want something like this.
For example,
resources/css/app.js need to store inside public/build/assets/css/app.js
resources/css/admin/member/index.js need to store inside public/build/assets/css/admin/member/index.js
resources/css/admin/lead/index.js need to store inside public/build/assets/css/admin/lead/index.js
**
It's similar for JS files too.**
Below is the code I tried.
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";
export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        outDir: "public/build",
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                "resources/css/app.css",
                "resources/css/vendor.css",
                "resources/css/app/layouts/cms.css",
                "resources/css/app/layouts/auth.css",
                "resources/css/app/layouts/page.css",
                "resources/css/app/layouts/admin.css",
                "resources/css/app/layouts/portal.css",
                "resources/js/app.js",
                "resources/js/bootstrap.js",
                "resources/js/vendor.js",
                "resources/js/sockets/all.js",
                "resources/js/layouts/smart.js",
                "resources/js/libraries/cs.js",
                "resources/js/libraries/skin.js",
                "resources/js/libraries/vertex.js",
                "resources/js/libraries/widget.js",
                "resources/js/app/layouts/bxslider.js",
                "resources/js/app/layouts/page.js",
                "resources/js/app/layouts/portal.js",
                "resources/js/app/modules/admin/managing/listing.js",
                "resources/js/app/modules/admin/member/member.js",
                "resources/js/config/core/dev/app.js",
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ], 
});

Could someone help me fix this? This is the 1st time I'm using Vite. I'm currently trying to manually upgrade the Laravel 5.2 project to Laravel 10. So I'm trying to keep most of the file structure the same.

You can archive it with rollupOptions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66863200/changing-the-input-and-output-directory-in-vite https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76943551/vite-configuring-multiple-entries-and-specific-output-structure

This question is similar to: Changing the input and output directory in Vite. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Files that do not need to be built can be placed directly in the public directory. There is no need to go through Vite.

@DamianChudobiński thanks for the help.

I fixed my issue after updating my npm vite package. Here is my solution if anyone has this issue again.
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";
import path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        outDir: "public/build",
        emptyOutDir: false,
        assetsDir: "static",
        sourcemap: true,
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                "js/app": path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/js/app.js"),
                "js/bootstrap": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/bootstrap.js"
                ),
                "js/vendor": path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/js/vendor.js"),
                "js/sockets/all": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/sockets/all.js"
                ),
                "js/layouts/smart": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/layouts/smart.js"
                ),
                "js/libraries/cs": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/libraries/cs.js"
                ),
                "js/libraries/skin": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/libraries/skin.js"
                ),
                "js/libraries/vertex": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/libraries/vertex.js"
                ),
                "js/libraries/widget": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/libraries/widget.js"
                ),
                "js/app/layouts/bxslider": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/app/layouts/bxslider.js"
                ),
                "js/app/layouts/page": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/app/layouts/page.js"
                ),
                "js/app/layouts/portal": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/app/layouts/portal.js"
                ),
                "js/app/modules/admin/managing/listing": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/app/modules/admin/managing/listing.js"
                ),
                "js/app/modules/admin/member/member": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/app/modules/admin/member/member.js"
                ),
                "js/config/core/dev/app": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/js/config/core/dev/app.js"
                ),
                "css/app": path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/css/app.css"),
                "css/vendor": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/css/vendor.css"
                ),
                "css/app/layouts/cms": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/css/app/layouts/cms.css"
                ),
                "css/app/layouts/auth": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/css/app/layouts/auth.css"
                ),
                "css/app/layouts/page": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/css/app/layouts/page.css"
                ),
                "css/app/layouts/admin": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/css/app/layouts/admin.css"
                ),
                "css/app/layouts/portal": path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    "resources/css/app/layouts/portal.css"
                ),
            },
            output: {
                entryFileNames: (chunkInfo) => {
                    if (chunkInfo.name.startsWith("js/")) {
                        return `${chunkInfo.name}.[hash].js`;
                    }
                    if (chunkInfo.name.startsWith("css/")) {
                        return `${chunkInfo.name}.css`;
                    }
                    return `${chunkInfo.name}.[hash].js`;
                },
                chunkFileNames: (chunkInfo) => {
                    if (chunkInfo.name.startsWith("js/")) {
                        return `${chunkInfo.name}.[hash].js`;
                    }
                    if (chunkInfo.name.startsWith("css/")) {
                        return `${chunkInfo.name}.css`;
                    }
                    return `${chunkInfo.name}.[hash].js`;
                },
                assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
                    if (assetInfo.name?.endsWith(".css")) {
                        return `[name].[hash][extname]`;
                    }

                    if (assetInfo.name?.endsWith(".js")) {
                        return `js/[name].[hash][extname]`;
                    }

                    if (
                        assetInfo.name.startsWith("fonts/") ||
                        assetInfo.name.startsWith("vendor/")
                    ) {
                        return `[name][extname]`;
                    }

                    return `[name].[hash][extname]`;
                },
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                "resources/css/app.css",
                "resources/css/vendor.css",
                "resources/css/app/layouts/cms.css",
                "resources/css/app/layouts/auth.css",
                "resources/css/app/layouts/page.css",
                "resources/css/app/layouts/admin.css",
                "resources/css/app/layouts/portal.css",
                "resources/js/app.js",
                "resources/js/bootstrap.js",
                "resources/js/vendor.js",
                "resources/js/sockets/all.js",
                "resources/js/layouts/smart.js",
                "resources/js/libraries/cs.js",
                "resources/js/libraries/skin.js",
                "resources/js/libraries/vertex.js",
                "resources/js/libraries/widget.js",
                "resources/js/app/layouts/bxslider.js",
                "resources/js/app/layouts/page.js",
                "resources/js/app/layouts/portal.js",
                "resources/js/app/modules/admin/managing/listing.js",
                "resources/js/app/modules/admin/member/member.js",
                "resources/js/config/core/dev/app.js",
            ],
            refresh: true,
            esm: true,
        }),
    ],
});

